# Android AppWidgetProvider and BroadcastReceivers

Tags: android, events, widget, provider, broadcast

The online android documentation says:

> Everything you can do with AppWidgetProvider, you can do with a regular BroadcastReceiver.

So, what i want to do is to register via `registerReceiver()` another event other than `ACTION_APPWIDGET_*` on my Widget. For example `ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY`, is there any way to do this? Obviously i cant register the event from the `onUpdate()` code but i should do it using a service or something else. The problem is that im not able to find any reference to the Provider (AppWidgetManager only returns AppWidgetProviderInfo objects).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

i think you would want to define your ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY intent filter in your AndroidManifest.xml and then override the onReceive and be sure to call super.onReceive to handle the appwidget dispatching.

Comment: I know that i can register the event on the manifest, but i want to do it via Java Code.